# Wifi hotspot on windows 8 and android

Tags: wireless-networking

I created a hotspot on windows 8 using http://www.talkofweb.com/creating-wi-fi-hotspot-in-windows-8-share-laptop-internet-connection/. However when I try to connect to it from an anroid phone it is stuck at obtaining IP address. Could someone please help me out? It looks like it is a problem with the DHCP. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Are you using WEP? I have found that with Internet Sharing on a Mac, Android devices don't like connecting if the security type is set to WEP.

Comment: I am using WPA-2

Answer (score -1):

You can try using my [Tutorial for creating a WiFi hotspot](http://www.knotrick.com/convert-your-windows-78-operating-system-pc-into-wifi-hotspot-router/)
You can manually configure the IP address on your Android device if it gets stuck at obtaining an IP address...

manual config:

```
gateway : 192.168.137.1
device ip : 192.168.137.10
router gateway : 192.168.137.1
dns : 192.168.137.1
```

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation in the answer**, otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. If you are not affiliated with the site, I recommend you say so to prevent this. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://superuser.com/help/promotion)